# Is there a way to partially specialize a template with parameter packs for a recursive function?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions, generic-programming, partial-specialization

I'm trying to make a print function in `C++` that takes in variable numbers of arguments and prints them each on their own line, like:

```cpp
template<typename Ty, typename... Types>
void println(Ty cur_line, Types... other_lines)
{
    std::cout << cur_line << '\n';
    println(other_lines);
}
void println() { std::cout << std::flush; }
```

However, if `Ty` happens to be a `std::vector<std::string>`, I want to treat it differently (because I want to print every element of the vector on its own line). I looked into partial specialization, but there doesn't seem to be much that I could find on doing so with parameter packs. Here's what I tried:

```cpp
template<typename Ty, typename... Types>
void println(Ty cur_line, Types... other_lines)
{
    std::cout << cur_line << '\n';
    println(other_lines);
}

template<typename... Types>
void println<std::vector<std::string>, Types...>
    (std::vector<std::string> cur_line, Types... other_lines)
{
    for (const auto& line : cur_line)
    {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
    println(other_lines);
}

void println() { std::cout << std::flush; }
```

However, I'm getting an MSVC error C2768: "`'println': illegal use of explicit template arguments`".
Any suggestions or solutions would be warmly welcomed! For reference, I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Preview and its corresponding compiler version.

Comment: function templates cannot be partially specialized, period. You'll need some user defined type magic for the required effect.

Comment: @TanveerBadar [cppreference on partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)

Comment: Yes, my point too. You are trying to do that to functions. That is not supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler way would be to have a print function and overload that:

```
template < typename T >
void print(const T& line)
{
    std::cout << line << '\n';
}

template < typename T >
void print(const std::vector<T>& line)
{
    for (const auto& element : line)
    {
        print(element);
    }
}

template<typename Ty, typename... Types>
void println(Ty cur_line, Types... other_lines)
{
    print(cur_line);
    println(other_lines);
}

void println() { std::cout << std::flush; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
/* main.cpp */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void PrintLine(const T &t)
 {
  cout << t << endl ;
 }

template <class T>
void PrintLine(const vector<T> &t)
 {
  for(auto &obj : t ) PrintLine(obj);
 }

template <class ... TT>
void PrintLines(const TT & ... tt)
 {
  ( PrintLine(tt) , ... );
 }

/* main() */

int main()
 {
  vector<string> list{"a","b","c"};

  PrintLines(1,2,3,list);

  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't partially specialize a function template, but you can overload it. Create a new overload of `println` that takes a `std::vector<std::string>` as the first argument and a general pack as the rest. Then do the special handling for the vector arg and forward the rest as before. Now your vectors will always be caught by the overload.